# using 'for' in shell script

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to create a script that will go through several steps on specific files in a directory.  Each step work file at a prompt.  It's when I use 'for' to work through the needed files that isn't working.

here is the script and starting text file.

```
#lab2dno.sh
#
#use cygwin
#cygwin
#work in %RAM%:\
cd '/cygdrive/e'
  # delete header lines
tail +4 preg.txt > file1.txt
  # split into herdcode.tx1 from %RAM% (e) in bash-3.2
awk -F "," '{close(f);f=$1}{ print > f".tx1" }' file1.txt
  #file list (no ext)
ls -1 *.tx1 | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/' > hc.ls1
  # delete extra fields (and rename works @ prompt))
  # cut -d "," -f 2,3,6 41300090.tx1 > 41300090.tx2
  # this one does not work
for i in hc.ls1; do cut -d "," -f 2,3,6 $i > $i.tx2;done
  # reorder fields and rename (works at propmt)
  # awk -F, '{ print $2,$3,$1}' *.tx2 > *.tx3
  # this one does not work
for i in *.ls1; do awk -F, '{ print $2,$3,$1}' $i > $i.DNO;done
```

...preg.txt...

```
MNDHIA Export

Name,Test Date,ID,Tag,Final Calculation,Symbols (Final Calculation),1,Parachek
41300090,1/25/2013,1636,56439256,-0.008,OPEN,1,Parachek
41300090,1/25/2013,1238,67046268,-0.017,OPEN,1,Parachek
41732189,1/29/2013,304,55567637,-0.006,OPEN,1,Parachek
41732189,1/29/2013,415,55646609,-0.007,OPEN,1,Parachek
```

Comment: By the way, the `-1` option (only one directory entry per output line) is implied (i.e., automatic) when you run `ls` with output to a file or a pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in hc.ls1; do cut -d "," -f 2,3,6 $i > $i.tx2;done
```

This won't work. Use `set -x` at the top of your script, it will turn on debug mode and echo every command.

What you're doing in the line above is set the value of `i` to `hc.ls1`. What you actually want is to set it to each value *listed inside* `hc.ls1`:

```
for i in $( cat hc.ls1 ) ; do cut -d "," -f 2,3,6 $i > $i.tx2;done
```